# Turn a string of a list to an integer in Python

Tags: python

I have an output of `a = "[1,2,3]"`, how do I convert it to an array `a = [1,2,3]` from the string in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ast` and then `ast.literal_eval()`

```
import ast
print(ast.literal_eval(x))
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
import json

result = json.loads("[1,2,3]")
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without importing stuff

```
lst = []

for index in range(len(a)):
    if a[index].isdigit():
        lst.append(int(a[index]))
```

Then lst will be a list containing all the integers in string a. And if you want to keep the variable name "a", you can

```
a = lst [::]
```